# 'if' statement with multiple conditions

Tags: objective-c, ios, if-statement

So I'm making a converter app, and I ran into a problem when using `if` statements to calculate my answer. I have a `UIPickerWheel` to select `convertFrom` and `convertTo`, and a `textField` for input.

My problem is that, using below mentioned code, the answer label just displays random units, not the ones selected in the `pickerWheel`.

I think that my fault is the `if` statements not checking for both to be the same thing, just one of them. How do I make it check for both to be true, or do it in a proper way?

[Download for full project](http://www.mediafire.com/?bmwosmfs2ir76oz)

Code:

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PickerView Delegate
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row
  inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    float convertFrom = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0]] floatValue];
    float convertTo = [[_convertRates objectAtIndex:[pickerView selectedRowInComponent:1]] floatValue];
    float input = [inputText.text floatValue];
    float to = convertTo;
    float from = convertFrom;
    float convertValue = input;
    float mtpaTilMtpaFloat = convertValue * 1;
    float mtpaTilMMcfdayFloat = convertValue * 2;
    float mtpaTilMillSm3dayFloat = convertValue * 3;
    float mtpaTilMMBTUFloat = convertValue * 4;
    float mtpaTilPJPAFloat = convertValue * 5;
    float MMcfdayTilmtpaFloat = convertValue * 0.5;
    float MMcfdayTilMMcfdayFloat = convertValue * 1;
    float MMcfdayTilMillSm3dayFloat = convertValue *6;
    float MMcfdayTilMMBTUFloat = convertValue *7;
    float MMcfdayTilPJPAFloat = convertValue *8;
    float MillSm3dayTilMTPAFloat = convertValue /3;

    NSString *mtpaTilmtpa = [[NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:
                             @" %f MTPA = %f MTPA", convertValue, mtpaTilMtpaFloat];

    NSString *mtpaTilMMcfday = [[NSString alloc ] initWithFormat:
                                @" %f MTPA = %f MMcf/day", convertValue, mtpaTilMMcfdayFloat];

    NSString *mtpaTilMillSm3day = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                   @" %f MTPA = %f Mill.SM3/day", convertValue, mtpaTilMillSm3dayFloat];

    NSString *mtpaTilMMBTU = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                              @" %f MTPA = %f MMBTU", convertValue, mtpaTilMMBTUFloat];

    NSString *mtpaTilPJPA = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                             @" %f MTPA = %f PJPA", convertValue, mtpaTilPJPAFloat];



    NSString *MMcfdayTilmtpa = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                @" %f MMcfday = %f MTPA", convertValue, MMcfdayTilmtpaFloat];

    NSString *MMcfdayTilMMcfday = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                   @" %f MMcfday = %f MMcfday", convertValue, MMcfdayTilMMcfdayFloat];

    NSString *MMcfdayTilMillSm3day = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                      @" %f MMcfday = %f MillSm3day", convertValue, MMcfdayTilMillSm3dayFloat];

    NSString *MMcfdayTilMMBTU = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                 @" %f MMcfday = %f MMBTU", convertValue, MMcfdayTilMMBTUFloat];

    NSString *MMcfdayTilPJPA = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                @" %f MMcfday = %f PJPA", convertValue, MMcfdayTilPJPAFloat];


    NSString *MillSm3dayTilMTPA = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                                   @" %f MillSm3day = %f MTPA", convertValue, MillSm3dayTilMTPAFloat];


    if (from = 1, to == 1) { resultLabel.text = mtpaTilmtpa;
    }
    if (from = 1, to == 2) { resultLabel.text = mtpaTilMMcfday;
    }
    if (from = 1, to == 3) { resultLabel.text = mtpaTilMillSm3day;
    }
    if (from = 1, to == 4) { resultLabel.text = mtpaTilMMBTU;
    }
    if (from = 1, to == 5) { resultLabel.text = mtpaTilPJPA;
    }
    if (from = 2, to == 1) { resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilmtpa;
    }
    if (from = 2, to == 2) { resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilMMcfday;
    }
    if (from = 2, to == 3) { resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilMillSm3day;
    }
    if (from = 2, to == 4) { resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilMMBTU;
    }
    if (from = 2, to == 5) { resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilPJPA;
    }
    if (from = 3, to == 1) { resultLabel.text = MillSm3dayTilMTPA;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Forgot to mention, the UipickerWheel selects a value 1-5 for the name of the units im converting, and that is just a reference number for my floats and strings.

Comment: You should be using `else if`s for all but the first `if`.

Comment: @NathanVillaescusa Can you give a detailed description on how I should use else if's?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have a single `=` in most of your statements. You should be using a double equals (`==`). A single `=` is going to assign the value to `from`, not check for equality. I would also replace the `,` with `&&`. One final thing to do is to combine the common parts of the `if` statements.

```
if (from == 1) { 
    if (to == 1) {
        resultLabel.text = mtpaTilmtpa;
    }
    else if (to == 2) { 
        resultLabel.text = mtpaTilMMcfday;
    }
    else if (to == 3) { 
        resultLabel.text = mtpaTilMillSm3day;
    }
    else if (to == 4) { 
        resultLabel.text = mtpaTilMMBTU;
    }
    else if (to == 5) { 
        resultLabel.text = mtpaTilPJPA;
    }
}
else if (from == 2) { 
    if (to == 1) {
        resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilmtpa;
    }
    else if (to == 2) { 
        resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilMMcfday;
    }
    else if to == 3) { 
            resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilMillSm3day;
    }
    else if (to == 4) { 
        resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilMMBTU;
    }
    else if (to == 5) { 
        resultLabel.text = MMcfdayTilPJPA;
    }
}
else if (from == 3 && to == 1) { 
    resultLabel.text = MillSm3dayTilMTPA;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i fixed that. It still does not work, for example, when i select the first name in the wheel, (1) (1), it does the calculation for (3) and (2). Can you explain this too?

Comment: @OscarApeland `if (from = 3, to == 1)` is an error, you want `if (from == 3  && to == 1)` instead (notice the `&&` operator instead of the comma).

Comment: Thanks, I will accept the answer in 6 minutes when i'm able to. That fixed the problem. Thanks alot to all of you.

Comment: I've made the code a little cleaner so that it doesn't have to check the `from` variable more than it needs to.

Comment: I know I'm off-topic, it doesn't concern that answer and I shouldn't do this... but I just saw you removed your answer on a question we answered almost at the same time. That's really humble! If only everybody were doing this, thread would have way less noise!

Answer (score 1):

Your use of all of these if statements doesn't scale well. You should have an array of arrays containing the labels. Then use the selected picker rows from the two components to access the elements from the arrays. Then all of your if statements get reduced to something like 3 lines of code.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are saying, but I think its harder because the units i'm converting are pretty advanced to calculate, and im new to programming.

Comment: Right now you have created a dozen or more variables to hold some labels and another dozen or more to hold some numbers. What happens when you need to support 20 more conversions? The solution is not to create 40 more variables and update your huge if-else block with 40 more checks. You want one variable that holds a list of the various conversion data. Then, based on the selected rows in the picker, you grab the matching data out of the list.

Comment: That seems to be beyond my understanding of coding. Would you please give me an example? :)

Comment: Look at the UICatalog sample app provided by Apple. Look at PickerViewController.m in that project. It shows how the data for picker is stored in an array. You would do something similar for your results.

Comment: Im still thinking about this stuff, and my brain is having a meltdown. I think i get it.
1. Every unit in the wheel has a number that is relative to a common variable for all units.
2. For example, if i had it to lenght instead of oil units, I would have the value of 1M = 1 and 1CM = 0.01. So when I wanted to calculate it, I would use inputText * to * from in a float. 
3. Would that work, just with a more complex common converting number?
4. If I did that, how could I make the result label display the units I am converting?